# Next.js: Dropdown not updating across modals

Tags: next.js, local-storage

For context, I'm using localStorage API for storing the collection datas. As you can see on the below GIF, I can add collection and the dropdown is updating it values. The problem is when you open the modal via other anime cards, the collection isn't using data from most updated `anime-collection` key value.

I need 10 reps to post image so here's [link to postimg](https://postimg.cc/fVTb2Tnz)

I'm sure the local storage mechanism is right, because I can see the `anime-collection` key is updated.

Here's my attempt in [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/typomulu/animexplore/) since I dont really know where did I go wrong.

Thank you!